# как можно создать колонку date в PostgreSQL

Tags: sql, postgresql, pgadmin4

Подскажите пожалуйста как я могу создать колонку с датой чтобы она сама генерировала дату при добавление данных? Можно ли такое вообще сделать?

Использую pgadmin PostgreSQl.14

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS test2 (
  Id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
  Date ????,
  Object text,
```

what should I write instead ???

Comment: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-createtable.html *GENERATED ALWAYS AS ( generation_expr ) STORED*

Comment: @Akina а что-то такое - `created_at TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP`?

Comment: @u_mulder Так это зависит от того, что автор имеет в виду. Если генерация по каким-то данным из записи (типа expired = created + period / discount) - то соотв. выражение в generated column. Ну а если просто дату создания записи - то created_at DATE DEFAULT CURRENT_DATE. А если дата - это на самом деле дата и время, то да, твой вариант.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS test2 (
  Id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
  Date date default NOW(),
  Object text,
```

Comment: Если нужно, укажите часовой пояс: SET TIMEZONE=’Europe/Samara’;

Comment: Спасибо, большое

Comment: Был рад помочь :)